# Textblob module in python is not working for me

Tags: python

Here is the code...

```
import textblob
While True:
    print("Ok...")
    print("Enter the text....")
    text = input()
    blob = textblob.TextBlob(text)
    blob.translate(to = "de")
```

It ask for text and then tells me Nothing. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Once you translate, try printing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example:

```
import textblob

while True:
    text = input("Which text you want to translate:")
    blob = textblob.TextBlob(text)
    print("--> {0}".format(blob.translate(to = "de")))
```

You forgot to print the German translated string

Answer (score 1):

You should declared the language you're translating from to your destination
example
translate(from_lang="en", to="es")